# Gwidgets how to make gedit uneditable

Tags: r, gwidgets

Any idea how to make the `gedit` textbox unable to be clicked or edited when the user selects a `radiobox` choice?
For example choosing `radiobox` a allows the user to use all 4 `gedit` and choosing `radiobox` b  allows the user to only edit the first `gedit` textbox.

Comment: use `enabled(instance) <- FALSE` to disable a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what jverzani said ,

```
         enabled(textBox_keyword1) <- FALSE
```

my textBox_keyword1 is the gedit object.